# Keep getting "resource cannot be found" until I edit controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC project is returning "The resource cannot be found" if I start the app without first making a change to one of the controllers.

If I go to a controller and just add a space, it works correctly. If I then go to a view, add a space, and hit Ctrl-F5 again, I get the error again. What's going on?

Comment: "What's going on?" is right. That's just dumb -- seems like there should've been a little hotfix by now, but can't find much about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this when I hit Ctrl-F5 because the URL that VS2008 uses is not the "right" route.  What I ended up doing was setting my project to always go to a specific route upon startup via the properties page.